# Netty combining messages

Tags: c#, java, tcp, netty

I have a `netty` server that writes string messages to a `C#` client similar to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    ctx.writeAndFlush("1;somestring");  // somestring is around 1000 characters long
}
```

The first message reaches my client fine, it's

```
1;somestring
```

But the next message is already

```
1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring
```

And after a few messages it even turns into

```
1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestri� // End of message
��ng1;somestring1;somestringng1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestr // Next message
ing1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;som // More randomly cut messages
estring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring1;somestring
```

I don' know what causes this � � �  or the line breaks at that point, or why the messages get combined like that and cut at random.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

This is the client code:

```
tc = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
tc.NoDelay = true;
tc.Client.NoDelay = true;
tc.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192;
ns = tc.GetStream();
writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
reader = new StreamReader(ns);

byte[] bytes = new byte[tc.ReceiveBufferSize];
ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: Could you split your messages, by adding `Environment.NewLine` to the end of string?

Comment: I could an end-token to every message but I would rather understand the problem. Also, some of the received messages start with `�` now instead of `1` and that would be hard to deal with.

Comment: Are you sure that you send UTF8, not an ASCII or whatever?

Comment: I think so, this is my pipeline



`ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", ish);
ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(maxIncMessageLength));
ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
ch.pipeline().addLast("gameStateHandler", gsh);`

Comment: Did you tried to run client app in debug mode and watch message lifetime?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. No I haven't done that. What's a message lifetime?

Comment: I mean to watch all values win debug mode step by step, this could help find where this mutation occurs.

Comment: Umm yeah could whoever downvoted my question at least tell me why?